Verification of legal Java version distribution included in Cytoscape install
Our institution is now requiring verification of legal licensing for Java distributions that are included in software installs. Does Cytoscape install include and utilize such licensing with its installation procedure and, if so, where is such documentation of that licensing located? Can it be available to the user? Where? How? Where can I find documentation that Cytoscape uses a licensed version of Java?

Cytoscape is shipped with the Eclipse Temurin OpenJDK from Adoptium.  The FAQ includes information about the license.
